# UIWebView loadrequest throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1

Tags: ios, uiwebview

So i have been using sqlite3 and blob which has pdf in it. I read it from db and after loading 2 request i get error in simulator.

ViewController.m

```
    #import 

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController {
        NSMutableArray *lights;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *lights;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lightname;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lighttype;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *lightmainimage;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *lightwebview;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) NSURLRequest *req;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) NSURL *targetURL;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *appFile;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) NSArray *paths;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *documentsDirectory;

    - (IBAction)GetLightListing:(id)sender;

    @end
```

ViewController.m

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "LightsList.h"
    #import "MyLightsList.h"

    @interface ViewController ()
    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    @synthesize lightname;
    @synthesize lighttype;
    @synthesize lightmainimage;
    @synthesize lights;
    @synthesize req;
    @synthesize targetURL;
    @synthesize appFile;
    @synthesize paths;
    @synthesize documentsDirectory;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        MyLightsList *mylights = [[MyLightsList alloc] init];
        self.lights = [mylights getMyLights];
        [self.lightmainimage setImage:((LightsList *) [self.lights objectAtIndex:0]).lightMainImage];
        [self.lighttype setText:((LightsList *) [self.lights objectAtIndex:0]).lightType];
        [self.lightname setText:((LightsList *) [self.lights objectAtIndex:0]).lightName];
        self.paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        self.documentsDirectory = [self.paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSError *error;
        self.documentsDirectory = [self.paths objectAtIndex:0];
        self.appFile = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datasheet.pdf"];
        if([((LightsList *)[self.lights objectAtIndex:0]).lightDatasheetPDF writeToFile:self.appFile options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"file suceed!");
        } else NSLog(@"file fail! %@",error);
        self.targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.appFile];
        self.req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.targetURL];
        [self.lightwebview loadRequest:self.req];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (IBAction)GetLightListing:(id)sender {
        static NSInteger currentIndex = 0;
        if(++currentIndex == [self.lights count]) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        } else {
            LightsList *aLight = (LightsList *) [self.lights objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
            [self.lightmainimage setImage:aLight.lightMainImage];
            [self.lighttype setText:aLight.lightType];
            [self.lightname setText:aLight.lightName];
            NSError *error;
            if([aLight.lightDatasheetPDF writeToFile:self.appFile options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"file suceed!");
            } else NSLog(@"file fail! %@",error);
            self.targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.appFile];
            self.req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.targetURL];
            [self.lightwebview loadRequest:self.req];
        }
    }
    @end
```

I'm sure the error is thrown on [self.lightwebview loadRequest:self.req]; because if i use stoploading after it, error wont happen or if i comment that line, but i really have no clue whats the problem here...

Comment: You should implement UIWebViewDelegate to see what is called before crash and what is not

Comment: After implementing delegate methods they both get loaded always (webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad), but didFailWithError doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in pdf files that were stored in blob as i opened them in preview and exported them again and saved them again to database it started working. They had obviously some invalid data which was causing this.